# Gatling Scala "not found: type ExtraInfo" error found when running performance test

Tags: scala, automation, performance-testing, scala-gatling

I am running into an issue where I'm getting an error when I am trying to develop a method to generate a simulation.log whenever I receive a status other than 200 and receive "KO". I was wondering if there is any solution in solving this issue?

**Error:**

```
scala:8: not found: type ExtraInfo
   def getExtraInfo(extraInfo : ExtraInfo): String = {
```

**Code:**

```
def getExtraInfo(extraInfo : ExtraInfo): String = {
if (isDebug
  || extraInfo.response.statusCode.get != TestData.successStatus
  || extraInfo.status.eq(Status.apply("KO"))) {
  ",URL:" + extraInfo.request.getUrl +
    " Request: " + extraInfo.request.getStringData +
    " Response: " + extraInfo.response.body.string
}
else
{
  ""
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scala type error could be caused by a missing import.

Try adding the following to your code -

```
import io.gatling.http.request._
```

You may also need to add `import io.gatling.commons.stats._` for Status if you don't have it already

Answer (score 0):

I found out according from Stephane message 
"You seem to be running Gatling master.
ExtraInfo is going away in Gatling 3, as it wasn't used in any official Gatling component and was a huge source of bugs."